# how to rename column label of a Serie (not index label)

Tags: python, pandas, series

**strong text**
I am strugling with something that should be easy. I am trying to rename **the column** of a Series (notice that I am *not trying to rename de index label*

```
s=pd.Series(['a','b','c','d')]
```

Thank you for any support.

BR,

Comment: Are you after `pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'], name='x'))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `name=` parameter in `pd.Series`:

```
s=pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'], name="vals")
```

Prints:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
Name: vals, dtype: object
```

---

Or use `.rename()`:

```
s=pd.Series(['a','b','c','d']).rename('vals')
```

---

If you want to convert the series to DataFrame, you can use `.to_frame()`:

```
print( pd.Series(['a','b','c','d']).rename('vals').to_frame() )
```

Prints:

```
  vals
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
```